# Можно ли зациклить for?

Tags: циклы, любой-язык, for

Преподаватель заявил, что, если кто-то зациклит for (именно успешно зациклит, я так понимаю, т.е., чтобы программа работала и выполняла какие-то функции), то она поставит зачёт автоматом. Я, конечно, понимаю, что это безумно, но реально ли это? И если да, то как?

Comment: какой язык нужен?

Comment: что значит зациклить? `for (;;);` ?

Comment: Бесконечный `for` на `Python`: `for _ in iter(int, 1): pass`

Comment: Препод у вас отмороженный. Таких я бы увольнял сразу.

Comment: @Egorithm зря...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ну есть много способов. Приведу примеры на C++.

- В цикле увеличивать переменную и сразу уменьшать:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    cout << "О как могу! \n";
    i--;
}
```

- Сделать цикл, в котором не изменять переменную, а присваивать:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i = 0) {}
```

или

```
for (bool i = true; i == true; i = true) {}
```

или

```
for (bool i = true; i == true;) {}
```

- Следующий вариант просто пропустить в цикле for вообще все, что можно:

```
for (;;) {
    
}
```

- И последний вариант, который дам: идти не в ту сторону, так что условие всегда будет верным:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1; i--) {
    cout << "To infinity and beyond!";
}
```

> Удачи!

Comment: последний пример с `i--` не сработает. Точнее будет работать долго до переполнения `int`, а потом вылетит из цикла.

Comment: @AntonMenshov вы правы. Ну тогда можно добавить условие, которое будет возвращать на нулевое значение, однако в таком случае это будет почти то же, что и 2 вариант

Comment: @Яков если мой ответ был вам полезен, то вы можете принять его, нажав на галочку. Таким образом будет понятно, что вопрос закрыт:) Если у вас есть вопросы, вы можете их задать:)

Comment: @AntonMenshov последний пример необязательно именно вылетит, это UB

Comment: @dIm0n у меня в visual studio просто вышел из цикла и завершил выполнение (но я брал не int, a short, чтобы не ждать 2млрд итераций), онлайн компиляторы тоже выходят из цикла. Может это и можно считать неопределенным поведением, но где и когда?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows

Comment: @dIm0n спасибо, но вы можете ткнуть мне на определенную строчку? Не хочу переводить все это, чтобы найти какой-то один момент

Comment: Так я и скинул определённый абзац. Там 3 предложения. В третьем сказано, что это UB

Comment: @dIm0n вы правы, спасибо:) Таким образом последний пример со 'звездочкой' и 'вопросиком'

Comment: @dIm0n согласен. позабыл об этом и положился на свой опыт. Ошибка стандартная. Повторю ее еще не раз :)

Answer (score 8):

```
#include <iostream>

#define continue goto my_for
#define for my_for:

int main()
{
    for
    {
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
        continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Чем не `for`? ;)

---

<sup>Контент для лиц старше 18 лет. Возможны приступы ярости и вспышки насилия. Не рекомендуется к просмотру беременным и людям пожилого возраста.</sup>

Comment: ну я тоже над чем-то таким думал, но тогда почему не `#define for while \n int main(){for (true){};return 0;}`?

Comment: @VictorVosMottor с `goto`  пострашнее) У меня самого мой ответ вызывает тошноту)

Comment: с goto не пострашнее, это ваще... ;)

Comment: кст помогай переоткрывать, я метку довесел.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor так у меня < 3000 репы:(

Comment: а, черт. ладн набирай давай быстрее;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottor к 2021 возможно справлюсь)

Comment: а че так медленно, я конечно тоже не чемпион, ну у вас чет ваще... тебе ж всего 200 надо.

Comment: @VictorVosMottor так я не спешу) (если честно, то у меня вредная привычка отвечать в комментах)

Comment: Переопределять ключевые слова и одновременно использовать стандартную библиотеку есть UB

Comment: @dIm0n Ответ - дно. Я не спорю. Мне интересно, кто эти 6 плюсанувших человек?:)

Answer (score 7):

Поскольку язык программирования пока неизвестен, то пусть будет Python:

```
for _ in iter(int, 1): 
    pass
```

Comment: Отлично! Не знал про такой вариант работы iter.

Answer (score 5):

Ну, как-то так можно попробовать:

```
#include <iostream>
int main () {

    int j = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i!=j; ++i){
        std::cout << "Гони зачет!" << endl;
        i = 0; 

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не компилируется же https://godbolt.org/z/eMjYnr

Answer (score 5):

Давайте ее удивим и завесим программу с пустым main();

```
struct A
{
    A(){for(;;);}
};

static A a;

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

Так можно нарисовать лабиринт:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A
{
    A(){for(;;std::cout<<(1&rand()?'\\':'/'));}
};

static A a;

int main() 
{
    return 0;
}

\//\\\\/\/\\\\\\//\//\//\///\//\\\////\\///\//\/////\//\\\\/\/\/\
/\\//\//\//\\//\\//\\\//\\\\////\\/\/\\/\/\//\\\/\\\\\\///\\/\\\/
//\\/\//////\///\\\//\\///\\\//\\\/\//\//\/\\///\\\\\//\/\\\\/\\/
////\/\\//\\\//\//\\\/\/\\/\\/\\/\\\\\\\\/\//\\\\////\//\/\///\\\
/\/\/\\\\/\/\//\\/\\///\//\\\\////\/\\//\\//\/\/\//\//\/////\//\\
\////\\\\\//\\\\\//\\/\//\\\\\/\\/\\\\/\//\\\/\//\\/\\///\\//\\\\
//\\///\\\/\/\\\/\\\\\/\//\\\\/\\\\/\\\//\\\/\/\/\////\///\\\/\\\
/\\\/\\\\///\\//\/\/\\//\/\\\//\\\/\\\\//\/\//\\\/\////\///\/////
/\\\/\\\\/\\/\///\//\\/\\\//\//\\\\///\\\\/\/\\///\\\\\\\\\/\\///
\//\/\/\\\\/\\/\////\\\//\\\\\\//\////\////\\\//\////\///\///\//\
```

Comment: крута!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1190385/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-for/1190395#1190395

Comment: Так просили зациклить цикл for, а не main

Comment: @МаксимФисман for и зациклили, только через макрос до выполнения main. В main ничего нет.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Не думаю, что это, что бы нужно Якову

Comment: @Konstantin_SH - здесь нет ни одного макроса

Comment: @gbg Ой, меня заглючило... Посмотрел на ответ с #define)) Тут через структуру конечно...

Answer (score 5):

C++

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    for (unsigned char i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
        std::cout << i;
}
```

Comment: Эм... а где тут зацикленный (бесконечный) for?

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, скомпилируйте, запустите и убедитесь, что цикл бесконечный ;)

Comment: Ну он всю ASCII выведет и кончится же.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, нет, не кончится.

Comment: Так ладно. А в чем фишка? unsigned виноват?

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, угу, `unsigned char` обычно может принимать значения только из отрезка [0, 255]. После инкремента `255` снова получаем ноль.

Comment: Разве гарантирован `[0;255]`? Может быть и более одного октета, несмотря на то что `sizeof` единицу возвращает (результат не в октетах, а в "кол-во char-ов" по сути)

Comment: @dIm0n, конечно же не гарантирован. Просто хотел немного "запутать" читающего код, а конструкция вроде `i <= UCHAR_MAX` мне показалась более привлекающей внимание :) Но вас так просто не подловить ;) Кстати, бесконечный цикл без побочных эффектов `for(;;);` тоже не гарантирует бесконечное выполнение. См.: [intro.progress/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.progress#1).

Answer (score 4):

## [c](/questions/tagged/c)-like languages:

```c
for (;;);
```

Ну и препод.

## Python ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253996/infinite-for-loops-possible-in-python)):

```py
def zero_to_infinity():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1

for x in zero_to_infinity():
    print(x)
```

```py
l = [1]
for x in l:
    l.append(x + 1)
    print(x)
```

Comment: Точно! Совсем забыл про это...

Answer (score 3):

## Пустой main через define

```
#define return for (;;);

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```